# is "everywhere" an adverb or a noun?

Tags: nouns, adverbs

I will get stronger everywhere above my hips.

Is "everywhere" an adverb or noun in this sentence?

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion that you could always look words up in any reputable dictionary before posting such simple questions. Everywhere could come as an adverb or a noun depending on the context. You can check for further info and examples here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/everywhere

Comment: What's an everywhere?